# 1 Channel / grey images for object detection using deep learning/cnn

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, object-detection

I have been working on object detection for some time, all the model that I have seen uses RGB only as input (well if we do not have 3 channel we copy data from one colour/dimension to other). 
Do we have any deep learning models where we can only feed 1 channel as input to the model, like the face/eye detectors (LBPHFaceRecognizer) in open cv.
Basically looking for deep neural networks that are simple and computational less demanding, when we have only 1 channel from sources like - thermal images, infrared cameras, TOF cameras, radars etc.

Comment: If I define a greyscale network which differs from a 3 channel network only by the number of input channels then only the first convolution layer will be less complex. The remainder of the layers will have the same number of parameter, outputs, and computational complexity.

Comment: From the computationally less demanding perspective, I think a search term you may be interested in is "mobile object detection network". For example MobileNetV2 looks promising, though I have no direct experience with it.

Comment: I was not aware that only the first layer of convolution can be reduced, I was expecting to get a greater reduction in the model as we have only 1 channel as input.

Comment: I have been using the mobile net v2 with TensorFlow object detection API, now planning to use Efficientnet on edge TPU.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong in this question to get a -1 vote !!

Comment: Probably because it falls in the category of either asking for off site resource or because any answer will be primarily opinion based. Both of which are considered not suitable for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use AutoML/NN architecture search for object detection then the neural network will be efficient to handle the various inputs (including grey images), the Mobile net v3 or Nasnet are good examples for neural architecture search.